# C macro to tag beginning and end of a function

Tags: c, assembly, c-preprocessor

This is nothing serious, it's only for my experiments, but never the less it annoys me that I can't compile this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MARK_ENCRYPTED_FUNCTION_START(NAME) \
    __asm__ __volatile__ (#NAME "_enc_start:")

#define MARK_ENCRYPTED_FUNCTION_END(NAME) \
    __asm__ __volatile__ (#NAME "_enc_end:")

#define GET_ENCRYPTED_FUNCTION_ADDRESS_AND_LENGHT(NAME, ADDR, LENGHT) \
    __asm__ __volatile__ (\
        "movl  $" #NAME "_enc_start, %0\n\t"\
        "movl  $" #NAME "_enc_end, %1\n\t"\
        : "=r"(ADDR), "=r"(LENGHT)\
    )

int f()
{
    MARK_ENCRYPTED_FUNCTION_START(f);

    {
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
        {
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    MARK_ENCRYPTED_FUNCTION_END(f);
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int f_addr, f_len;
    GET_ENCRYPTED_FUNCTION_ADDRESS_AND_LENGHT(f, f_addr, f_len);

    printf("f - addr start: %x; addr end: %d\n", f_addr, f_len);

    return 0;
}
```

The output from `gcc -E test.c` is this:

```
int f()
{
 __asm__ __volatile__ ("f" "_enc_start:");

 {
  int sum = 0;
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
  {
   sum += i;
  }

  return sum;
 }

 __asm__ __volatile__ ("f" "_enc_end:");
}


int main()
{
 unsigned int f_addr, f_len;
 __asm__ __volatile__ ( "movl  $" "f" "_enc_start, %0\n\t" "movl  $" "f" "_enc_end, %1\n\t" : "=r"(f_addr), "=r"(f_len) );

 printf("f - addr start: %x; addr end: %d\n", f_addr, f_len);

 return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the linker can't find "f_enc_end". Linker error is:

> /tmp/ccqB886f.o: In function `main':
>   test.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `f_enc_end'.

It is more puzzling because it can find `f_enc_start` that is built in a similar way:

> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Any suggestion, no matter how small in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: anyway you can get a dump of the (unlinked of course) object file? it could be more helpful  `g++ -c test.c` maybe

Comment: made it to compile. see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution in the end. I had to rewrite the C code this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MARK_ENCRYPTED_FUNCTION_START(NAME) \
    __asm__ (#NAME "_enc_start:")

#define MARK_ENCRYPTED_FUNCTION_END(NAME) \
    __asm__ (#NAME "_enc_end:")

#define GET_ENCRYPTED_FUNCTION_ADDRESS_AND_LENGHT(NAME, ADDR, LENGHT) \
    __asm__ __volatile__ (\
        "movl  $" #NAME "_enc_start, %0\n\t"\
        "movl  $" #NAME "_enc_end, %1\n\t"\
        : "=r"(ADDR), "=r"(LENGHT)\
    )

MARK_ENCRYPTED_FUNCTION_START(f);
    int f()
    {

        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
        {
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum;
    }
MARK_ENCRYPTED_FUNCTION_END(f);

int main()
{
    unsigned int f_addr, f_len;
    GET_ENCRYPTED_FUNCTION_ADDRESS_AND_LENGHT(f, f_addr, f_len);

    printf("f - addr start: %x; addr end: %x\n", f_addr, f_len);

    return 0;
}
```

Now it compiles and reports start and end addres. Now i have to implement the actual encryption.

The question will remain open in case anyone have something to share.